# Let $EX = 2$ and $Var(X) = 5$, Find $E(3X^2 + 4)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Not sure how to work this one. I know one can take the constant $3$ out as well as the added $4$ so we have $3\cdot E(X^2)+4$, but I'm not sure how to calculate $E(X^2)$ given the information.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** By definition, we have

$$\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}^2 [X]$$

Comment: It follows from context, but $E^2(X)$ seems like $E(E(X))$.

Comment: @Jonh No. I'm just taking the square.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that from the definition of variance we have the formula:

Var($X$)=$E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Comment: Not exactly the definition of variance. The definition is $Var(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)$. This formula follows at once from here but... Just wanted to point out.

Comment: You are right, I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic formula $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$;

$$
E(3X^2+4)=3Var(X)+3E(X)^2+4=31.
$$